# Perl calling methods with and without parentheses

Tags: perl, subroutine

Some Perl books advise using parentheses when calling class methods, saying this helps to keep the parser from having to guess the intent of the code.  However almost all Perl code I have seen (including modules on cpan) very rarely uses the parentheses when calling methods without arguments.

Is it normal to leave off those parentheses or should I always type them.

I wrote a small test code to measure the difference between calling a method with and without parentheses and it really shows a small difference between 1% and 2% for a class with two methods only. I imagine this could raise up if the class is large.

here is the test script I used to benchmark:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Benchmark qw(:all);

{
    package Messages;

    sub new {
        my ($self) = @_;
        return bless {}, $self;
    }

    sub message {
        my ($self) = @_;
        return "Hello world";
    }

    sub another {
        my ($self) = @_;
        return "Another Hello world";
    }
}

my $class = Messages->new();

cmpthese(10_000_000, {
    'with   ()  ' => sub { $class->message() },
    'without    ()  ' => sub { $class->message },
});
```

and this is the results of the benchmark:

```
                 Rate       without ()       with ()    
without ()      3320053/s          --         -1%
with    ()      3338898/s          1%          --
```

I imagine if the application uses hundreds of modules and each module has hundreds of methods called without parentheses, should this adds up a lot of speed difference?

If so, why everyone is coding without parentheses?.

Answer (score 8):

The 1% difference is system noise. Both version compile to exactly the same bytecode, so there can't be a systematic difference between them. Use whichever variant makes your code easier to read.

If you want to see what it compiles to, you can do that like this:

```
perl -MO=Concise -E '$foo->bar()'
```

Comment: B::Deparse is useful too:
`perl -MO=Deparse,-p -E '$foo->bar()'`

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure the 1% time difference is all that meaningful, and I doubt you'd be able to measure any difference in a real program.

Some people think it looks neater without `()` at the end of a method-call. That's enough justification. You'll see it with functions too.

For me, I try to do so when I want to imply "no parameters required here". Mostly just with attribute getters and such.

If a method can take optional parameters and they're just being defaulted then I prefer not to, so I can distinguish between "no parameters required" and "I haven't supplied parameters, but could have".

Comment: Readability is more important than some very minor performance optimisation (if any).  I'll use whichever I think makes my code more readable. In practice, that tends to boil down to whether it's an accessor method or if it does something more substantial. E.g. `print $object -> result,"\n";` vs. `$object -> take_over_the_world();`

Answer (score 3):

There's some history here. If you don't want to read it all, know that the `()` resolve a particular parsing thing that lets Perl know that you're using a subroutine and not a bareword. I tend to always use `()` for empty argument lists. I'm curious which Perl books you think make that advice though.

### What am I?

Perl uses sigils to denote namespaces (and access, but put that aside). Scalars have `$`, arrays have `@`, and so on. Before Perl 5, subroutines had `&` (and along with that had a [crypto context](https://www.foo.be/docs/tpj/issues/vol3_1/tpj0301-0003.html)). There's a difference between these two:

```
&uses_current_stack;  # subroutine uses the current @_
&no_arguments();      # subroutine with no arguments
```

Perl 5 did away with the need for an explicit `&` before subroutine calls. That allows for two more possibilities, one of which is now ambiguous:

```
&uses_current_stack;  # subroutine uses the current @_
&no_arguments();      # subroutine with no arguments
bareword;             # maybe a subroutine?
subroutine();         # subroutine with no arguments
```

That `bareword` might be a subroutine, but maybe it isn't. It depends on things that may have happened far away from its use.

This program compiles just fine, but as you see in the decompilation, Perl doesn't quite know what `foo` is:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'foo'
'???';
-e syntax OK
```

This is the same problem even if the subroutine definition shows up later:

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'foo; sub foo { print 1 }'
'???';
sub foo {
    print(1);
}
-e syntax OK
```

If you forward declare that `foo` will be a subroutine name. Now the parser has a hint about what to do even though you never actually define the subroutine. A subroutine doesn't need a definition until you call it, and Perl is a dynamic language so that definition may show up later. You can also forward declare the subroutine but having its definition show up before its use (although most people put the subroutine definitions at the bottom of a program, out of the way):

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'use subs qw(foo); foo'
use subs ('foo');
foo();
-e syntax OK

$ perl -MO=Deparse -e 'sub foo { print 1 }  foo'
sub foo {
    print(1);
}
foo();
-e syntax OK
```

### Arity

There's another thing to know about Perl. You can leave off the parentheses on subroutine calls, and Perl will try to figure out if the next tokens are arguments for that subroutine.

Consider a `print`, which takes a list of arguments. So, all of these become arguments to `print`:

```
print 1, 2, 3, 4, 5;   # 12345
```

But some things take a set number of arguments, `rand` knows it takes one argument. Where there was `4`, there's now the result of `rand`. The `5` still comes from the `5` argument:

```
print 1, 2, 3, rand 4, 5; # 1232.764206311960175
```

It's easier for many people to read to use parens to denote the the reader what Perl already knows:

```
print 1, 2, 3, rand(4), 5; # 1232.764206311960175
```

Now consider functions that take a range of arguments, such as `split`. There's the pattern to use, the target string, and a maximum number of items. All of those arguments are optional though.

```
split;                # split on whitespace on $_, unlimited
split /\h+/;          # split on horizontal whitespace on $_, unlimited
split /\h+/, $var;    # same, with $var
split /\h+/, $var, 2; # split into limited number of items
split /\h+/, $var, 2; # split into limited number of items
split /\h+/, $var, 2, $arg; # oops
```

So now, looking at this, what do we intend for `split`? Turns out this is a trick because `split` complains about too many arguments:

```
print 1, 2, split /\./, '1.2.3.4', 4, 5;  # error
```

Parentheses resolve that:

```
print 1, 2, split( /\./, '1.2.3.4' ), 4, 5;
```

Or maybe you wanted to work on `$_`:

```
print 1, 2, split( /\./ ), '1.2.3.4', 4, 5;
```

It seems like a silly case, but more complicated examples boil down to the same thing.

### On to methods

Perl methods always require parentheses around a non-zero list of arguments:

```
$invocant->method( 1, 2, 3 );
```

As an aside, Raku has the method colon to grab everything after it as arguments. I didn't like this at first, but now I miss it in Perl 5:

```
$invocant->method: 1, 2, 3;  # Raku
```

Perl does not require parens around zero arguments to a method, so either of these are fine:

```
$invocant->method();
$invocant->method;
```

The thing after the `->` is the method, and arguments go in parentheses. There's no guessing there.

But, Perl being a dynamic language has another trick. You can have a method name in a variable and use that variable on the right side of the `->`. This now requires the `()` again, even for an empty argument list:

```
my $method = 'some_sub';
$invocant->$method();
```

## Wrapping up

But, you know that Perl 4 had this `&` going on and not using parens did the weird default argument thing, so you used `()` to make the empty argument list. And, you remember that there's the long range effects. So some people use `()` to denote what they want. Others are more comfortable knowing what Perl's going to do.

From that, some people like to do things the same everywhere. So even though one case might not need it, since they are doing that somewhere else, they do even when it's not needed. Other don't don't care as much.

In something like [Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com), we know you're going to see a lot of different things so we show a lot of different things. There's the code you write, but there's also the code you didn't write but have to read.

Answer (score 1):

Because you can. Really. I think.
As Perl allows so much, people are using it. Sometimes for the good, as you are able to write very complicated stuff in short sequences, and sometimes for the worse as it often gets complicated (especially for people new to Perl).

As well it depends on what your program does. The difference should be only on compile time (I assume). Often times compile time is a short part of the full application lifecicle, where it doesn't matter so much.

Comment: If it is a compile time only, why this difference in run time as you see the benchmark above.

Comment: 1% could have been caused by other reasons on a system. Not sure if I would count on that too much. But that sure is a fair point. Using the parentheses is better practice, I definitely agree on that. As said, people probably doing it otherwise because they can.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a systematic error in your measurement. When I run your code, `without    ()` beats  `with   ()` every single time. But when I use strings of the same length in `cmpthese` e.g.:

```
cmpthese(10_000_000, {
    'with    ()' => sub { $class->message() },
    'without ()' => sub { $class->message },
});
```

I got these (rather expected) results:

```
                Rate with    () without ()
with    () 3412969/s         --        -1%
without () 3460208/s         1%         --

                Rate without () with    ()
without () 2994012/s         --        -0%
with    () 3003003/s         0%         --

                Rate without () with    ()
without () 3278689/s         --        -1%
with    () 3300330/s         1%         --

                Rate with    () without ()
with    () 3039514/s         --        -2%
without () 3105590/s         2%         --

                Rate without () with    ()
without () 3267974/s         --        -3%
with    () 3378378/s         3%         --
```

So I think it's only about the best practices.

Comment: The Benchmark module methodology has an uncertainty around 7%. If the differences you are seeing are under that number, the differences are insignificant.