# How Mojolicious modifies Perl syntax

Tags: perl, syntax, mojolicious

Reading Mojolicious [minions documentation](https://mojolicious.io/blog/2018/12/10/minion-stands-alone/) I found the following code:

```
use v5.28;
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use experimental qw( signatures );
use Time::HiRes qw( time );

plugin Minion => {
    SQLite => 'sqlite:' . app->home->child('minion.db'),
};

# ...
app->start;
```

How did they create a new syntax `plugin Minion => {...}`? I've never seen it in classic Perl books. Is it a function call with a hash parameter: "Minion" being a key and a hashref `{...}` is a value?

Also they call `app->start` - `app` is a function returning a blessed hashref? But if it was a hash why "start" is not enclosed into braces? This syntax looks strange to me.

Comment: It's not actually syntax. They're just functions with prototypes. You can read the source to see how it's done.

Comment: You could see this in [Intermediate Perl](https://www.intermediateperl.com) and the barnyard object tutorial :)

Comment: Somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25523983/perl-calling-methods-with-and-without-parentheses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`app` is a function which returns `$app` which is an instance of `Mojolicious::Lite=HASH`

`app->start` is same as `app()->start`

https://github.com/mojolicious/mojo/blob/24d1d1987dbfbe27eaaa37dd5db692d2deb8d07f/lib/Mojolicious/Plugin/Config.pm#L12-L14

```
"sub app; local *app = sub { \$app }; use Mojo::Base -strict; $content";
                             |
                             ^ not a reference but escape
                             due to eval() of double quoted string
```

Reproduction

```
perl -MMojolicious::Lite -E 'no warnings; sub foo; local *foo = sub { app }; say for foo, app'
```

output

```
Mojolicious::Lite=HASH(0xe72080)
Mojolicious::Lite=HASH(0xe72080)
```

`plugin` is a regular function

```
perl -MData::Dumper -wE 'sub plugin { print Dumper \@_ } plugin Minion => { SQLite => "sqlite:" }'
$VAR1 = [
          'Minion',
          {
            'SQLite' => 'sqlite:'
          }
        ];
```

You can add parens, and drop fat comma to look like the usual function call,

```
plugin("Minion", { SQLite => "sqlite:" });
```